# Rails 3.2.18, Unable to get font-family

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, woff, eot

I created a fonts.css.scss file in fonts folder and given below format

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'amandaregular';
  src: url(font-path('amanda-webfont.eot'));
}
```

it's generating with compiled fonts, but unable to load font-family

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'amandaregular';
  src: url("http://localhost:3000/assets/amanda-webfont.eot");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you add the fonts folder to the Asset pipeline load path in **config/application.rb**, and then restart your server:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

Then place fonts.css.scss in **app/assets/stylesheets** and make sure it is included in your application.scss manifest. It should look like:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'amandaregular';
  src: url(font-path('amanda-webfont.eot?#iefix')) format('embedded-opentype');
}
```

Notice the above uses the [Fontspring @font-face syntax](http://blog.fontspring.com/2011/02/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax/).

Finally, make sure that the file **amanda-webfont.eot** is saved in **app/assets/fonts**

Comment: Yes, i have already defined in application.rb, and given format('embedded-opentype'), still font-face don't change

Comment: I edited my answer. You need your fonts.css.scss saved in your stylesheets folder, but the font file itself saved in the fonts folder.